# Saving parfor loop data in workspace (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, for-loop, nan, parfor

Good evening,
May I please get help with a script I'm writing? I have a parfor loop nested within a for loop. The goal is to iterate over a set of data that consists of 10 data subsets generated from an earlier parsim simulink analysis (it's labeled as *1x10 SimulationOutput*). Each data subset is 24 rows deep, and a variable length of columns (usually about 200,000 to 300,000 columns of data). Part of the process is to find the maximum or minimum values in each data set. Once that is done, it is to be put into a table, appending data to that table. Ideally, I should have a 6x10 table by the end of it. See below for the code:

```
% Run Time
tic

% Preallocate memory to increase speed

b=zeros(24,1); %Make space for this array.
c=zeros(500000,1);
d=zeros(500000,1);
e=zeros(500000,1);
f=zeros(500000,1);
g=zeros(500000,1);
h=zeros(500000,1);
%table=[];

for j = 1:length(out(1,:)) %iterate over each run

    parfor i = 1:length(out(1,j).PN.time) % Set length of vector
        b=out(1,j).PN.signals.values(:,i); % Find the values to work on
        c(i)=b(19,:); % Distance to target (m)
        d(i)=b(20,:); % Lat. Accelerations, integrated twice (m)
        e(i)=b(21,:); % Long. Acceleration, integrated twice (m)
        f(i)=b(22,:); % Lat. Guidance Error
        g(i)=b(23,:); % Long. Guidance Error
        h(i)=b(24,:); % time to target (sec)
   
    end
   
    %For c_min, there's extranous zeros popping up, exclude them
    tc = c;
    tc(tc <= 0) = nan;
    [c_min, I_1] = min(tc);
    %    [c_min,I_1]=min(c(c>0)); % Collect the closest missile/target approach (most 
    critical value)
    
    [d_max,I_2]=max(d); % We need to find the max value per run, but wish for the min value 
    %over all runs.
    
    [e_max,I_3]=max(e); % We need to find the max value per run, but wish for the min value 
    %over all runs.
    
    [f_min,I_4]=min(f); % We just want the minimum value here.
    
    [g_min,I_5]=min(g); % We just want the minimum value here.

    [h_max,I_6]=max(h); % The minimum time is 2nd most critical value, after distance to 
    %target.

    table(:,j)=[ c_min d_max e_max f_min g_min h_max]; %d_max e_max f_min g_min h_max

end

toc
```

The issue that I am having is that, while I can input the correct data sets in the correct locations in the table if I set a constant j value (example: if j = 7, then the 7th column in the table gets the correct data) I can't seem to get all the values inputted correctly. What I mean is that, the outputted table (6x10) will have repeated values across columns, values from one column in another column, and so on). It is as if the script cannot differentiate between columns anymore, so values just go wherever.

If anyone has any advice, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thank you,

Comment: Does it work if you use `for` instead of `parfor`? No? Then you have a bug. Yes? Then MATLAB has a bug.

Comment: You should really make the outer loop the parfor loop, that is always the most efficient way.

Comment: I’m not familiar with Simulink outputs. Is any computation done when you do `out(1,j).PN.signals.values(:,i)`? Or are you just copying data out of an array in this loop?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I get the same answer with "for" as with "parfor".

Comment: I'll make the outer loop the parfor loop, and the inner for.

Comment: Nope, the line `out(1,j).PN.signals.values(:,i)` just simply reads the data coming from `out`. `out` is the data set generated by an earlier `parsim` run.

Comment: To expand on my last comment, `out(1,j).PN.signals.values(:,i)` uses the outer `for` loop to iterate over each data subset (so j has a maximum value of 10), while `i` loops over each column within each data set.

Comment: Then why not read the full rows? What’s the purpose of the inner loop? `c= out(1,j).PN.signals.values(19,:);` and so on.